# How to delete all the subfolder under some folder in Ant?

Tags: ant

Suppose I have

```
/Root
    /A
        /to_delete
        /not_to_delete
    /B
        /to_delete
        /not_to_delete
    /C
        /to_delete
        /not_to_delete
```

How to delete those folders called "to_delete" in Ant?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete folders except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619692/delete-folders-except-one)

Comment: I fighted a lot with it at the time, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25668084/1783163) is what you really wanted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please check this :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html

If you don't want to specify A, B, C you will have to do some nasty trict for recursively searcing all subdirectories. I have done this with a custom java script.

If you can specify A,B,C though you just need something :

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
  <fileset dir="root" includes="**/to_delete/"/>
</delete>
```

Comment: No. I don't want to specify A,B,C I don't know the name when I delete, but I know under that folder there is folder called "to_delete". It is not possible using Ant only?

Comment: Well it depends on what you mean Ant only :). I do not think there is a recursive search / delete task. You can write your own in one of the supported BSF languages.

Comment: I was trying to use: <delete>
   <dirset dir="Root">
    <include name="**/to_delete"/>
   </dirset>
  </delete> It seem doesn't work

Comment: The `**` part _is_ the recursive search. So `includes="**/to_delete/"` will work. Simply strip `/A` from `dir` and try it. Also note the trailing `/` after `to_delete/`.

Comment: I though he wanted to delete directories only under A B C. Editing.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the below code and it works to remove the dir and sub dirs as well.

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="true">
  <fileset dir="${dir.to.delete}"> 
    <include name = "**" />
    <exclude name = "**/.svn" /> <!-- in case you want to skip .svn folders to avoid SVN conflicts -->
  </fileset>
</delete>
```