# Delete folders except one

Tags: ant

Under the src folder I have the following folders: daos, business and model. I want to delete using ant script, all the folders except "model". So I tried:

```
   <delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
    <include name="**/*"/>
    <exclude name="model/*"/>
    </fileset>
   </delete>
```

All the folders are deleted, except "model" which is empty. All its files are deleted.

Comment: I've tested this and it works. As I undrstand you want to delete all folders except model with its files?

Comment: yes, that s what I want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try instead

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src">
        <include name="**/*"/>
        <exclude name="**/model/**"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Comment: It does an unneeded recursive subtree search, which can took long time and is useless.

Answer (score 10):

To the googlers of the future:

What worked for me:

```
<fileset dir="target">
    <include name="*/"/>
    <exclude name="big_and_complex_dir/"/>
</fileset>
```

This deleted everything (every files *and* directories) below `target/`, except `target/big_and_complex_dir`.

My intended goal was to avoid the unneeded directory walkthrough, which in case of the "`big_and_complex_dir`" took very long time.

It seems the fileset interpretation of ant has the non-trivial, non-intuitive behavior, that we need to close an include/exclude path with `/` if we intend to do recursive subdirectory operations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> ```
> <delete includeemptydirs="true">
>   <fileset dir="${basedir}/src" includes="**/*" excludes="model/" defaultexcludes="false"/>
> </delete>
> ```

It deletes all the folders and their subdirectories & files except the model folder and its subdirectories & files under src folder.